# Vim: Change the file format for a particular directory

Tags: vim, file-format

I'm using Vim to work on a project with others developers using Windows.

The problem: I get "^M" characters instead of line-breaks. This can be solved with this simple command

```
:set fileformats=dos
```

But when I restart Vim, the file is opened again with the unix format. Another problem is that I have to execute the command for each file in the directory.

Is it possible to set this parameter for a whole directory?

Comment: You could probably get somewhere with per-directory vimrc's. Search for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fileformats` option is [global](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format). The `fileformat` option however is local to each buffer.

With the following command you can check how those are set:

```
:verbose set ff? ffs?
```

In my `.vimrc` I have set the following:

```
set fileformats=unix,dos,mac
```

And it Just Works.